# Count number of palindromes in a list of strings, Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, palindrome

The function countPalindromes receives a list of strings and returns a count of how many of the strings are palindromes.

```
isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome w = w == reverse w

countPalindromes :: [String] -> Int
countPalindromes ss = length filter (== isPalindrome) ss
```

I know that the function length is applied to two arguments instead of one. I just don't know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't follow you. This code is equivalent to `length (filter (== isPalindrome) ss)`. What do you say that `length` is applied to two arguments ?

Comment: I think a first issue is the `filter (== isPalindrom)`. Why do you expect that to list all palindromes in the string?

Comment: Ah indeed, a `map` is missing here.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No, `length filter (== isPalindrome) ss` is parsed as `((length filter) (== isPalindrome)) ss`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: no, furthermore the problem is a bit underspecified, do we count overlapping palindromes?

Comment: @M.Aroosi Ah ok. So this code does not compile. I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use parentheses to affect function application:

```
countPalindromes ss = length (filter (== isPalindrome) ss)
```

The parentheses will cause the entire expression `filter (== isPalindrome) ss` to be grouped into a single term, and its result passed on to `length`.

This will get you to the next error; I encourage you to read it carefully and see if you can make progress from here yourself, then open a fresh question if you spend, say, fifteen minutes trying to understand it without making progress.

Comment: I'm glad I read your answer carefully before pointing out the error in `filter (== isPalindrome) ss`.