# Match type error when counting palindromes in a list in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, palindrome

I'm getting a match type `[Char]` with `String -> Bool` error:

```
isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome w = w == reverse w

countPalindromes :: [String] -> Int
countPalindromes ss = length (filter (== isPalindrome) ss)
```

`countPalindromes` uses `isPalindrome` to check if a string is a palindrome.

I now have a different issue than in [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49498908/2751851) about this palindrome count task. The first issue was solved, and I was instructed to open a new question to solve the new issue. Which is why this is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isPalindrome :: String -> Bool`, which is to say that it expects a string, then gives you a boolean to say whether or not that string is a palindrome.

`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, which is to say that it expects two values of typeclass `Eq` (in other words: anything equatable) and tells you whether or not they are equal.

Pair those together and you get `(== isPalindrome) :: (String -> Bool) -> Bool`*. You've handed `(==)` a `String -> Bool` value, so it's expecting one more and will tell you if the two are equal. That's not quite what you want, though. You're not comparing two functions....

In fact, you're not comparing any two things at all. You only want to see which values passed to `countPalindromes` return `True` when called by `isPalindrome`. That's what `filter` is for!

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

It's looking for an `a -> Bool` to pass as the first argument. This is the function that will be deciding what makes it through the filter and what doesn't, and in this case you want to use some derivation of `isPalindrome`. Looking again at `isPalindrome` in this context we see:

```
isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
```

that looks an awful lot like an `a -> Bool` function! Let's try substituting all the `a`s in `filter`'s type signature with `String`.

```
filter :: (String -> Bool) -> [String] -> [String]
```

That looks like it's exactly what you're wanting! Try, then, using `filter isPalindrome` instead of `filter (== isPalindrome)`.

---

* nitpick: functions (more generally: values of type `(-> r)`) are not members of the `Eq` typeclass so you'd actually get an error saying that you can't tell if a `String -> Bool` is equal to another `String -> Bool`. It's not relevant to the problem at-hand, though, so I'm pretending that's not an issue and burying this explanation down here.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified the problem! :)

Comment: Note that you can go one step further than this. The law of function composition is that well-behaved functions follow the rule: `f (g x) == (f . g) x`. In this case `f` is `length` and `g` is `filter isPalindrome`, so you can rewrite this as `(length . filter isPalindrome) ss`. Once you have an argument on its own at the end of a function body you can omit it from the LHS and RHS of the function, so it can condense down to `countPalindromes = length . filter isPalindrome`, which is idiomatic Haskell!

Comment: I'm not sure that's really a *law*, so much as the definition of `(.)`. What would an ill-behaved function look like? It also implies there are multiple, non-trivially different implementations of `(.)` that would obey the law.

Comment: @chepner You're right, I'm playing fast and loose with definitions here and mixing up some terms (I was thinking of the functor laws, including `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g`, which does not hold for ill-behaved functors). *Mea culpa*.

Comment: Terminology matters aside, it is worth noting that the composition law of `Applicative`, `u <*> (v <*> w) = pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w` does look a lot like `u (v w) = (u . v) w`, and that is no coincidence -- in fact, for `Identity` the law amounts to exactly that.